# Convert string to variable name

Tags: c#, xml, reflection, deserialization

I have an XML file, I have a node and I read all ChildNodes. The name of the childNode match to a variable I have to set with the value of this childNode.

In the loop, I'd like set :

- myvar1 to MyValue1
- myvar2 to MyValue2

The C# Code :

```
protected string myvar1;
protected string myvar2;
```

The XML content look like this :

```
<parameters>
 <myvar1>MyValue1</myvar1>
 <myvar2>MyValue2</myvar2>
</parameters>
```

C# set variables :

```
    foreach (var item in xmlParamInstallation.SelectNodes("parameters")[0].ChildNodes)
    {
        ??????
    }
```

Any idea ?

Thanks,

**UPDATE 1:**
the value "field" in the loop is null all the time.

```
public class ParametersTest
{
    public string myvar1 { get; set; }
    public string myvar2 {get; set;}
}

var type = typeof(ParametersTest);
foreach (XmlNode item in xmlParamInstallation.SelectNodes("parameters")[0].ChildNodes)
{

    var field = type.GetField(item.LocalName);
    field.SetValue(field, item.InnerText);
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you just use `XmlSerializer` to do this? It is more efficient than using reflection manually.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it using [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

```
var type = typeof(SomeClass);
var field = type.GetField(item.Name);
field.SetValue(null, item.InnerText);
```

**RE: UPDATE 1**

```
var parameters = new ParametersTest();
var type = parameters.GetType();

var s = @"<parameters>
            <MyVar1>MyValue1</MyVar1>
            <MyVar2>MyValue2</MyVar2>
           </parameters>";

var xmlParamInstallation = new XmlDocument();
xmlParamInstallation.LoadXml(s);

foreach (XmlNode item in xmlParamInstallation.SelectNodes("parameters")[0].ChildNodes)
{

    var field = type.GetProperty(item.LocalName);
    field.SetValue(parameters, item.InnerText, null);
}
```

Comment: First: Your xml node names doesn't match the properties names including case-sensitivity. Second: you are using properties, so you need to call `GetProperty` instead of `GetField`.

Answer (score 5):

If you are seeking to assign variables based on the names of nodes in XML, you have at least a couple options:

- Deserialize the XML structure into an object with corresponding member names
- Populate the variables using reflection
- Populate the variables using dynamic method calls/expression trees that know how to read the contents of the XML node into an object property.

All of these approaches suggest a more object-oriented approach to the problem then just populating a few variables, but it would be easy to create a lightweight structure with the appropriate members which is populated by reading the XML document.

You could also use a key-based collection (like a `Dictionary<string, string>`) to store the values if you are just looking to build a simple name/value collection from the source XML.

Answer (score 3):

If you put the names and values in a dictionary, you can easily get the values by name:

```
Dictionary<string, string> parameters =
  xmlParamInstallation.SelectNodes("parameters")[0].ChildNodes
  .ToDictionary(n => n.Name, n => n.InnerText);

myvar1 = parameters["myvar1"];
myvar2 = parameters["myvar2"];
```

Comment: I don't want set variable one by one (if possible)

Comment: Well, you can do it using reflecction, but I like to give an alternative without reflection. Besides, this way *you* control which properties are set, not the contents of the XML file.

Answer (score 2):

You could either do as "Default" said, or you could look into Reflection. By using the `Type.GetMember(string)` method you could find a member with the given name (the tag name in your XML) and set its value.

**EDIT**
Samich beat me, so I'll give him +1 - he's got sample code as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out the [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/71s92ee1.aspx) class