# Getting a string to be a variable name

Tags: c#, winforms

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8723960/convert-string-to-variable-name) question but it's being used with an XML file so I don't really understand what is going on.

What I want to do is get my list of objects to get populated in my for loop. Right now I have this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dogs.Length; i++)
{
    dogs[i] = new Dog();
}
dogs[0].PictureBox = picDog0;
dogs[1].PictureBox = picDog1;
dogs[2].PictureBox = picDog2;
dogs[3].PictureBox = picDog3;
```

I want to do something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dogs.Length; i++)
{
    dogs[i] = new Dog();
    dogs[i].PictureBox = StringToVariable("picDog" + i); 
}
```

`PictureBox` is a property field in case that makes a difference.

StringToVariable() is the thing I don't know about. I don't even know what it would be called to search for it.

Comment: Why don't you just use array of `picDogs` instead of 4 variables? Then your code will be `dogs[i].PictureBox = picDog[i];`

Comment: You can use Reflection, but I think it not good solution in your case

Comment: Thanks guys. I'll try these both tonight. @YuriDorokhov how would I use Reflection. Can you show me some sample code?

Comment: Please do not use `Reflection` in such a scenario. There are many pitfalls here, e.g. what happens if you rename the variable `picDog` in your code? You will get `compile time` errors everywhere you use the variable but the `Reflection` part will fail at `runtime`, which is way worse and much harder to trace.

Comment: Where are the picDogn pictureboxes created?  What container holds them?

Comment: I've heard of properties. And I've heard of fields. But I've never heard of a "property field". What you mean by that?

Comment: @PeterDuniho Sorry I just meant a property. I don't know all the terminology just yet.

Comment: @cdkMoose They are created in the Form1.cs[Design]. The form is their container.

Comment: @FunLamb, Peter Duniho's answer is the extension of my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible to say for sure without [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). But I would expect that the following statement should work in your scenario:

```
dogs[i].PictureBox = (PictureBox)Controls.Find("picDog" + i, true)[0];
```

That will search the children of the current control (which I assume in this case is your `Form` subclass) for each control in turn. This is somewhat inefficient, as it has to search the controls collection for each item, but as long as you have a relatively small number of items, this is likely not a problem.

Depending on how your `Form` is set up, the following might also work:

```
string prefix = "picDog";

foreach (PictureBox pictureBox in Controls.OfType<PictureBox>())
{
    if (pictureBox.Name.StartsWith(prefix))
    {
        int index;

        if (int.TryParse(pictureBox.Name.Substring(prefix.Length), out index))
        {
            dogs[index] = pictureBox;
        }
    }
}
```

That version inspects each child control just once, attempting to parse an index appended to the initial text of `"picDog"`, and if it's successful, using that index to assign to your array directly. This has the advantage of scaling well to larger lists of controls, but may be overkill in your case.

Note that in both of the above examples I've left out any error checking. In either example, you would probably want to add some kind of handling in case (for the first example) the desired control couldn't be found, or (for the second example) if you find a control for which you can't parse the index, or fail to fill in one of the elements of the `dogs` array.

If for some reason neither of the above examples seem to work for you, please edit your post so that it includes a better code example.

Comment: This is great thanks. I'll to stick to a good, minimal, complete code example for my next question. Thanks for bringing that up. I didn't know about it.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes a simple solution can work well. How about this?

```
var picDogs = new [] { picDog0, picDog1, picDog2, picDog3 };
for (int i = 0; i < dogs.Length; i++)
{
    dogs[i] = new Dog();
    dogs[i].PictureBox = picDogs[i]; 
}
```

---

You could even do this:

```
var dogs = new [] { picDog0, picDog1, picDog2, picDog3 }
    .Select(picDog => new Dog() { PictureBox = picDog })
    .ToArray();
```