# Create variable which will be named with listValue

Tags: c#

I'm having a little problem with creating variable which will be named by list value.

Here is an example with what I want.

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
  //here I want to create variable
  //which will be named with list[i]
}
```

So if list has 2 elements eg.

```
list[0] = "testName"
list[1] = "andAnotherOne"
```

I want to create 2 variables,
one of them is named testName and the second one andAnotherOne

Can you help me complete it?

Comment: This is not possible in C#. Your next best approach is a Dictionary. You can then access the values by a string key. But variable must have a name before you can compile.

Comment: If you want to store Key&Value go for dictionary. Otherwise this is nonsensical, because after compilation the variables will have completely different names.

Comment: _after compilation the variables will have completely different names._ Um. There is no _after_ because ther is no _before_ because one simply can't write it down.

Comment: @TaW Yes, you are right. There are no variables created during runtime, and existing ones will renamed during compilation.

Answer (score 1):

Just create A `List<string> names = new List<string>()`;

```
   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
   {
      names.Add("sample" + i);
   }
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to refer with names then use a dictionary like below,

```
Dictionary<string, string> myvalues = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

Comment: How would that help? A Dictionary maybe, but he wants to relate names to values, not just indices.

Comment: but second part says list[0] and list[1] as values

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need a `Dictionary` as said by TaW. This allows you to have the value same as the index.

```
Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dictionary.Add("foo","foo"); //index,value of index
if(dictionary.ContainsKey["foo"])
{ 
    string value = dictionary["foo"];
    Console.Write(value);
}
```

I hope I understood your question.

Comment: What you mean? I'm new to this, is there an etiquette to answering questions? Sorry if there is. Also, I dont fully understand what hes asking for. So I did a general example

Comment: Your answer is fine. I just meant, since he has posted code with a list of names you could use it to create the entries..

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dynamic` and `ExpandoObject`:

```
var variables = new List<string> { "variableOne", "variableTwo" };

dynamic scope = new ExpandoObject();

var dictionary = (IDictionary<string, object>)scope;

foreach (var variable in variables)
    dictionary.Add(variable, "initial variable value");

Console.WriteLine(scope.variableOne);
Console.WriteLine(scope.variableTwo);
```

Answer (score 0):

In C#, variables are all statically declared. I think you can't do that. Maybe you can try with the reflection but I think it won't able you to do what you want.

Some things I found that could interest you :

[string to variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293549/string-to-variable-name)

[Convert string to variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8723960/convert-string-to-variable-name)